# Shadcn Select is having issue with dynamically generated SelectItem

Tags: reactjs, select, react-hook-form, zod

I am having an issue with `Shadcn` react library's `Select` component. It seems that "dynamically" generated `SelectItem` is causing an issue were they are not displayed in the `SelectValue` box when selected.

I am using Zod validation library. I am supposed to select from available types of properties. The selection works and Zod is getting the value. But the item is not being displayed in the select box. It is just showing empty

```
<FormField
control={form.control}
name="type"
render={({ field }) => (
<FormItem className="grid grid-cols-4 items-center gap-4">
   <FormLabel className="sm:block sm:text-right">
      Type
   </FormLabel>
   <Select
      disabled={isSubmitting}
      onValueChange={field.onChange}
      defaultValue={field.value}
      >
      <FormControl>
         <SelectTrigger className="col-span-4 sm:col-span-3">
            <SelectValue placeholder="Select a property type"/>
         </SelectTrigger>
      </FormControl>
      <SelectContent className="SelectContent">
         {propTypes.map((type) => (
         <SelectItem key={type.id} value={type.id}>
            {type.name}
         </SelectItem>
         ))}
      </SelectContent>
   </Select>
</FormItem>
)}
/>
```

[image]

I am not seeing the value selected:

[image]

However, Zod is getting the value successfully:

[image]

Now, if I replace the dynamically generated values with static values as below, it will work, and I will be able to see what I selected:

```
<SelectContent>
   <SelectItem value="m@example.com">m@example.com</SelectItem>
   <SelectItem value="m@google.com">m@google.com</SelectItem>
   <SelectItem value="m@support.com">m@support.com</SelectItem>
</SelectContent>
```

Something is wrong when we generate the `SelectItem` dynamically.

Here is a codesandbox view:

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/elastic-andras-35r33x

Any idea what is wrong here or how to fix it?

Thank you all.

Comment: can you provide some basic example with codesandbox

Comment: Ok, I just included a link to the codesandbox. Can you help?

Comment: I am still stuck

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else had the same problem. There is something that many are missing. The `SelectItem` `value` must be in `string` value. Don't assume that you will get this converted for you.

It should be like this:

```
<SelectContent className="SelectContent">
         {propTypes.map((type) => (
         <SelectItem key={type.id} value={type.id.toString()}>
            {type.name}
         </SelectItem>
         ))}
</SelectContent>
```

I hope this will help anyone who found the same issue

Comment: Didn't help. My category.id is already a string

Comment: @ShubhamJangle, that's the point. Even if your id is a string. You have to use toString() anyway. I am not sure why. But this is how I did it

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are missing `value={field.value}` in `<Select />` component

Here is the working example component. Here we have product form with categories in select component. I have tested this myself.

```
const ProductForm: React.FC<any> = ({ product }) => {
  const form = useForm<ProductFormType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(ProductFormSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      categoryId: "",
    },
    values: {
      categoryId: product.categoryId, // initial value
    },
  });

  async function onSubmit(values: ProductFormType) {
    // handle Submit
  }

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-8">
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="categoryId"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Category</FormLabel>
              <Select
                onValueChange={field.onChange}
                defaultValue={field.value}
                value={field.value}
              >
                <FormControl>
                  <SelectTrigger>
                    <SelectValue placeholder="Select a category" />
                  </SelectTrigger>
                </FormControl>
                <SelectContent>
                  {categories.map((category) => (
                    <SelectItem key={category.id} value={category.id}>
                      {category.name}
                    </SelectItem>
                  ))}
                </SelectContent>
              </Select>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <Button type="submit">submit</Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I need to wait until dynamic values are fetched and the default value is selected in the form.

I'm using `form.reset({// the default values that I fetched.})` to set the default values on the form without making `dirtyFields`

After that just add conditional rendering around your `FormField`.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled with the same problem. And solution for me was to retrive proer element from options array and assign it to default value. Analogously in your case it would look like this:

```
defaultValue={propTypes.find(type => type.id === field.value.type)?.type}
```

Possible you should adjust a liitlebit this code to your field properties. I hope I have helped!

Comment: Thank you for the effort. But as I mentioned in the fix, the issue was that the value should have been a string not a number. And that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

add type.name in value while creating selectItem. It should work

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding relative class in `<FormItem />`. Then add the CSS properties of `position: absolute` and `z-index` of higher number, say `z-index: 999` in `<SelectContent />`.

That might solve the issue, sometimes `<SelectItem />` section goes underneath the form.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, due to the fact that `shadcn` uses radix in itself and when you are importing the select component, it is probably wrongly imported from radix and you just need to import it from the select component related to `shadcn`.

This was the problem with my code and I realized it after a few days:

```js
// Wrong import:
import { SelectItem, SelectValue } from "@radix-ui/react-select";

// Correct import:
import {SelectItem, SelectValue  } from "@/components/ui/select";
```

Comment: No, that wasn't the case. The import is correct and this is not related to the issue

Comment: Anyway, now my code works